# Обновить страницу ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

У меня есть `ViewPager`, страницы которого листаются с помощью табов. Ну так вот, поделал я что-то на второй странице, присвоил `Boolean changed = true;`, теперь, нажав на `tab1` ( Ну или листнув экран) ), как-то хочу:

**1.** Переслать эту переменную на первую страницу
 **2.** Как-то получить ее на первой странице
 **3.** Если переменная `true`, допустим, вывести тост с текстом *changed*

Как это возможно сделать? Ну результат должен быть такой - на первой странице у меня есть переменная, которую я могу использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Создайте интерфейс типа `callback`, и при помощи него оповестите `Activity` или `adapter` `ViewPager`'a об изменении данных
2. Используйте библиотеку событий, например `EventBus`.
3. Используйте `BroadcastReceiver`, Например `LocalBroadcastReceiver` Для оповещения

Comment: А что быстрее или удобнее всего?

Comment: @MrKlonwar, Если нужно только в этом месте *в обратном порядке* оповещать классы, то первый вариант. Если нужно, чтобы на это событие отреагировали одновременно и другие классы, то второй, или третий. Я лично использую третий, но у меня обычно все компоненты приложения обмениваются информацией с его помощью